# ChildView. pager view style won't work in ipad, works in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am trying to make an app that works on both iPad and iPhone. I have ensured my project's deployment is targeting the universal device family. 
The issue that I am having is that my code isn't showing my mainViewcontroller class on an iPad. This same code is working fine when run on any iPhone.

The mainViewcontroller looks like this:

[This is main Subview which should be subview of image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ivmF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCwgN.png)

[this one is the main topview -> stays for 5 different sub controller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ivmF.png)

This is what I am seeing in preview section on the storyboard:
[iphone8 is showing the viewController but nothing is shown on the iPad pro 9.7"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UoXm.png)

If anyone can help me figure out the issue please let me know.
I might have to make a new project that focuses only on iPad.

Comment: Try to post code instead of links

Comment: try to check your constraint again

Comment: yeah there was constraint that I didnt awere of.. copy and paste error.... thanks!